# Function is not defined error in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-components, angular-controller

When I use this script:

```
<script>
    function TestClick() {
        alert("Test clic");
    }
</script>
```

With this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <input name="BtnAddNew" type="button" value="Load all OPCVM" onclick="TestClick()" />
</div>
```

It works.

But once I try to put everything inside a controller :

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>PetitsTests</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        var myApp= angular.module("myApp", []);

        myApp.controller('OPCVMViewModel', function ($scope, $http) {
            function TestClick() {
                alert("test clic");
            }
        }); 

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="OPCVMViewModel">
        <input name="BtnAddNew" type="button" value="Load all OPCVM" onclick="TestClick()" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Then I get a `"TestClick is not defined"` error...

Comment: Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 0):

Example from the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#adding-behavior-to-a-scope-object):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
}]);
```

In short, you must attach whatever functions or properties you declare inside your controller to `$scope` in order to make them avaialbe to your template/view:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('OPCVMViewModel', function ($scope, $http) {
    function TestClick() {
        alert('Test click');
    }

    $scope.TestClick = TestClick;

    // or:

    $scope.TestClick = function() {
        alert('Test click');
    };
});
```

Also, as JohnMoe has pointed out in the comments, there are other issues in your code.

First of, you should not use onclick, but [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). You can find the [full list of `ng` directives here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive).

Moreover, the `controller as` syntax is the recommended way to go as from Angular 1.2, even though it will work without it.

Instead of writing something like:

```
app.controller('FooController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.property = 'Foo';
});
```

You replace `$scope` for `this`, and now you don't need to inject `$scope` and have a nicer class-like looking controller:

```
app.controller('FooController', function () {
    this.property = 'Foo';
});
```

Your templete will look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FooController as vm">
    {{ vm.property }}
</div>
```

If later on you decide to create a directive, it will look something like this:

```
app.controller('FooController', function () {
    this.property = 'Foo';
});

app.directive('fooDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'FooController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '{{ vm.property }}'
    };
});
```

Also, you could use proper `ES6` classes with a transpiler. Take a look at [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/es6/2015/01/23/exploring-angular-1.3-using-es6.html) if you are interested

Comment: I would upvote, but `controller as` syntax should be used in favor of `$scope`

Comment: i replaced my code with this :
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller('OPCVMViewModel', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  
            $scope.TestClick = function TestClick() {
                alert("test clic");
            }
        }]);
But I still get the same error.

Comment: @JohnMoe Should be `ng-click="..."` in the DOM, not `onclick="..."`. Angular does not hijack the native onclick attribute/functionality, rather, it has its own.

Comment: @JohnMoe That's right, I didn't notice you were not using `ng-click`. As @mhodges pointed out, you should use Angular's `ng` directives instead of native event handlers. Also, the `controller as` syntax is the way to go as of Angular 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try

```
$scope.TestClick = function(){   alert("test click");   };
```

And then in the button HTML:

```
type="button" ng-click="TestClick()"
```

In short, functions needs to be defined in scope. and use ng-click to call the function.